# SVG contentDocument null when SVG loads dynamic in Ionic3

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, svg

I am creating mobile app using ionic framework.
I have load SVG in my view as follow

```
<object id='svg-container' type="image/svg+xml" [data]="svgUrl" >
Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

When i trying to get SVG contentDocument with following code

```
var mySvg = document.getElementById("svg-container");
mySvg.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log((mySvg as HTMLObjectElement).contentDocument);
}, false);
```

Its working fine when SVG path is from internal assets folder, but it's not working when SVG loading from the server, its returning null in the content document 
[image]
In the screenshot, svg-container has a document loaded, but contentDocument is returning as null
How can I get inner document when SVG is loaded from URL, not from the asset folder.
It has nothing related to the website, I am looking for the solution for the hybrid mobile app.

Comment: You mean you can't access the content of a cross-origin resource? That's pretty normal.

Comment: I tried to first download the file in internal storage and then load SVG, but still not working.

Comment: I also tried downloading file, convert that to base64 and then load content.

Comment: Yes, dataURI is seen as cross-domain. You may have more luck with blobURI, but not on IE. Loading your svg normally from the same domain should work though.

Comment: I am not running it on the website, I am compiling mobile app with ionic framework.

Comment: Question you mark as duplicate is for website, not for mobile app.

Comment: Which will run a browser instance on the device your app will run from. The Cross-Origin restrictions still apply in your ionic web-app...

Comment: But what if i load from local device storage?

Comment: Did it with work around by doing http call on that url and get xml with ajax call.